# Is making my co-tenants sign a contract to pay their share of the bills helpful in court?

Tags: united-kingdom, contract-law, evidence, rules-of-court

I share a house with three other people, and as I was the first to move in, I had to sign up for some of the bills with my name. However, some of my co-tenants are rather slow and unwilling to pay their share on time, and I'm getting worried that I might be taken for the proverbial ride, especially when university terms finish and some of them might leave before our tenancy contract is finished (it is until the end of summer, so they'd be forced to pay the rent, but I would have no way to make them pay the bills).

I had an idea of printing out some forms stating that the people who sign it would thereby agree to pay the bill in full (specifically internet bills, where whether you use it or not the price stays the same). Would this be of any help in court? I hope it won't come to this but I want to have some sort of backup plan if things go awry.

Comment: What incentive do they have to sign any such document?

Comment: @SteveMelnikoff it'd just be a tangible confirmation for what we have agreed verbally

Comment: This is not taken care of anywhere in the existing lease?

Comment: @Shadylamp - sure, but what Steve is asking is more like why would your co-tenants want to sign this new document when they're already getting the services you've signed up for? What would you do if they didn't sign the document?

Comment: @brhans If it comes to worse I could block access to the internet, which in my opinion is fair if they're not willing to pay for it anyway

Comment: @A.fm. unfortunately not, the internet contract is separate from the lease